When does the HDCP patent expire?
My understanding is that the DRM enforcement mechanism in modern display formats such as HDMI, DP and DVI are based on High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP).  This is protected by law such that:

In order to make a device that plays HDCP-enabled content, the manufacturer must obtain a license for the patent from Intel subsidiary Digital Content Protection LLC, pay an annual fee, and submit to various conditions.

I cannot find what patent this is.  Wikipedia links the HDCP Specification Rev1_3 which has revision dates from 1999 to 2006.  Patents tend to last 20 years in the US, so it seems likely this patent may be expiring soon.
Will the HDCP patent be expiring soon?  If so, will it be legal to produce devices that freely implement this algorithm and allow copy protection to be breached?

IANAL but strongly suspect that even if "allow[ing] copy protection to be breached" would no longer be in breach of patent law, you would still be in breach of copyright law.

@TripeHound I would expect it to be similarly legal to libdvdcss, legal to have and distribute but illegal to commit breach of copyright.

The reason for DRM hardware/software is because it's hard to catch and prosecute small-scale copyright violations, so instead they use technology to make it difficult to commit in the first place. You may be able to provide such technology after the patent expires, but you'd likely be committing contributory infringement. It probably violates the DMCA.

The security of the system isn't due to the patent, which has to publicly describe the protected invention. The security of the system is dependent on the keys/certificates which aren't affected by patents.

@user71659 The keys are known because they cannot do maths, and work arounds are available.  Currently Intel will sue anyone they can, but one would expect that to change after the patent expires.
